# Compiling methods for optimal runtime performance

Tags: c#, performance, code-generation

I'm trying to determine what the best way to get fully optimized delegates for various objects to improve the speed of serialization. Simply put: I'd like to remove various different checks, and compile more efficient serialize functions one time at the start of my app.

Let's take a look at this simple example:

```
public class GamePacket
{
    [Length(10)]
    [ReadBackwards]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I'd likely create a serializer, and for performance reasons store the attributes in a cached field. Everytime I want to deserialize a GamePacket from a stream (or byte array), I'd call something like:

```
Deserialize(byte[] stream)
{
    var header = stream.ReadByte();
    var packet = cachedDeserializers[header];

    var instance = packet.DelegateForCreateInstance();

    foreach (var field in packet.Fields)
    {
        if (field.Type != TypeCode.String) continue;

        var str = stream.ReadBytes(field.LengthAttribute.Length);

        if (field.HasReadBackwardsAttribute)
            str = str.Reverse();

        field.DelegateForSetValue(instance, str);
    }
     
}
```

The problem now lies in the fact that EVERY time I'm calling Deserialize on that stream, I need to loop through and check various things like attributes, and other checks. In the example, these things can potentially be omitted (And maybe more):

- `if (field.Type != TypeCode.String) continue;`
- `if (field.HasReadBackwardsAttribute)`

If I know the field has a read backwards attribute, I'd like to compile a simplified delegate on app start that omits these checks, and simply reads it backwards. Is it possible to create a delegate that can remove unneeded logic? For example:

```
Deserialize(byte[] stream)
{
    var header = stream.ReadByte();
    var packet = cachedDeserializers[header];

    var instance = packet.CallCachedCompile(stream);
}

// CallCachedCompile for GamePacket would look something like this:
CallCachedCompile(byte[] stream)
{
    var instance = this.DelegateForCreateInstance();
    var str = stream.ReadBytes(10);
    str = str.Reverse();
    this.DelegateForSetValue(instance, "Id", str);
    return instance;
}
```

I've looked briefly into expression trees. Would something like this be doable in expression Trees? What would be the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using code generation approach you can generate delegates for the particular type. So instead of this generic reflection-like code:

```
foreach (var field in packet.Fields)
{
    if (field.Type != TypeCode.String) continue;

    var str = stream.ReadBytes(field.LengthAttribute.Length);

    if (field.HasReadBackwardsAttribute)
        str = str.Reverse();

    field.DelegateForSetValue(instance, str);
}
```

You can generate code for a specific type:

```
gamePacketInstance.Id = SomeConvertionToString(stream.ReadBytes(field.LengthAttribute.Length).Revers());
```

The code generation topic is quite big and I don't know what exactly you do inside your delegates. You can generate specific delegates in runtime (emit il or expression trees) or in compile time (source generators). I suggest you to read my article [Dotnet code generation overview by example](https://dev.to/maximtkachenko/dotnet-code-generation-overview-by-example-1m16). It will give good overview with examples.

Comment: Here's an example of my current deserialize function for an individual field: https://gist.github.com/danbopes/27f45f5b61cee834701a0bb30552eed0. It's quite massive, and will likely be growing as I add more and more packets. Just trying to simplify it so I don't have to go through checks/loops every time I do deserialization.

Comment: In the mists of going through your link, I stumbled upon actual code generation as of .net 5. I think expression trees may be a bit too much additional code headaches, and I can simply just extend/generate the Serialize methods on the classes themselves (Based on the attributes), that write the code even easier, such as:

`function Deserialize(Stream stream)
{
    Id = stream.ReadString(10);
    Id = Id.Reverse();
}`

Answer (score 0):

Without using any code generation you can still do this pretty efficiently.

You basically need to use generics and polymorphism to cache all code that you want done for each type that you encounter.

Bearing in mind that properties have underlying methods, we can create delegates to set properties without using code generation.

```cs
abstract class DeserializerBase
{
    object DeserializePacket(Stream stream);
}

class Deserializer<T> : DeserializerBase where T : new()
{
    FieldAction<T>[] fieldActions =
        typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.Type == TypeCode.String)
        .Select(p => IsReverseAttribute(p)
                     ? new FieldActionReverse<T>
                     {
                         Setter = p.SetMethod.CreateDelegate<Action<T, string>>(),
                         Length = GetLengthAttribute(p),
                     }
                     : new FieldAction<T>
                     {
                         Setter = p.SetMethod.CreateDelegate<Action<T, string>>(),
                         Length = GetLengthAttribute(p),
                     })
        .ToArray();

    object DeserializePacket(Stream stream);
    {
        var packet = new T();
        foreach (var action in fieldActions)
            action.Deserialize(packet);
    }
}

class FieldAction<T>
{
    public Action<T, string> Setter;
    public int Length;

    void Deserialize(Stream stream, T instance)
    {
        var str = ReadString(stream);
        Setter(instance, str);
    }

    virtual string GetString(Stream stream)
    {
        return stream.ReadBytes(Length);
    }
}

class FieldActionReverse<T> : FieldAction<T>
{
    override string GetString(Stream stream)
    {
        return stream.ReadBytes(Length).Reverse();
    }
}
```

Your final entry code becomes this.

```cs
Dictionary<int, DeserializerBase> cachedDeserializers = new Dictionary<int, DeserializerBase>
    {
        {5, new Deserializer<GamePacket>()}
    };

Deserialize(Stream stream)
{
    var header = stream.ReadByte();
    var packet = cachedDeserializers[header].DeserializePacket(stream);
}
```

You can even place generic constraints on `T` to ensure it is a `Packet` then you can return a base `Packet` type from this entry function.

Comment: You still have the `if (Reverse)` statement in there which is being run/checked every time, so I don't see how any of this code makes deserialization more efficient?

Comment: True, but you are checking a single cached field, rather than rechecking the field attributes on each run. You could take it out and use more polymorphism (I have edited to this) but not convinced it's any more efficient. A single `bool` check is pretty fast, and virtual function calls can sometimes be slower (either way we're dealing in nanoseconds)

Comment: ok, I see your edits, and I see what you're getting at, but the real downside is that you're essentially creating lambdas for every possibility. If you take a look at my deserialize function in mtkachenko's comment you'll see my Deserialize is rather complex, has lots of if/else statements, and creating a field action for every possibility is insane.

Comment: True, which is why I recommend you go with pre-caching the checks into fields. I really don't think that matters, the point is that no reflection is done at all at runtime, there is just a single startup cost of creating the operators/actions

Comment: My goal is simple: Cached field is still an instruction in memory which needs to do a compare. Goal is simple: Remove the logic needed, compile the instructions one time at the start into lambda's/delegates to have a truly streamlined function. I should be able to get that functionality from code generation.

Comment: When you're processing thousands/tens of thousands of packets per second, those instructions add up. Sure there's no reflection, but I've already taken that out of the equation. Now, I'm looking for even more performance from there.

Comment: Possibly yes compiled expression trees may then be worth it, although GC is likely to actually be your biggest headache, rather than a couple nanoseconds for a single extra jump instruction. For example, you are reading data into strings, rather than keeping them as array spans etc.